# Angular CRUD parsing ID on resource remove

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm trying to write a function to remove an answer:

```
// Remove an answer
$scope.removeAnswer = function(answer) {
  Answers.remove(answer._id);
};
```

However, I am throwing the console error:

```
DELETE http://localhost:9000/api/answers?0=5&1=4&10=7&11=4&12=2&13=c&14=0&15=0&16=0&17=0&18=0&19=0&2=7&20=0&21=0&22=0&23=4&3=3&4=d&5=0&6=1&7=4&8=2&9=d 404 (Not Found)
```

When I `console.log(answer._id)`, I get a reasonable id like `348374831`...

Why is it converting the id to a weird format and how can I fix it?

Here seems to be an identical question, although the answer doesn't really explain the problem:  [AngularJS resource - encoding url string parameter as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657056/angularjs-resource-encoding-url-string-parameter-as-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corect way to do it is:

```
$scope.removeAnswer = function(answer) {
  Answers.remove({
      id: answer._id
 });
};
```

or instead of `id` use the corect name you used in the `$resource` factory definition.
Example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

`$resource` expects `object` parameter. Here's an example in [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#credit-card-resource)